# Filestream not closing after feature

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

My framework (C#/Selenium) runs its settings from an external file using filestream

```
        string strFilename = @"C:\Config\GlobalConfig.xml";
        XPathDocument document = null;
        using (FileStream reader = new FileStream(strFilename, FileMode.Open,
                          FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            document = new XPathDocument(reader);
        }
        XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();
```

the framework is told to read this config file before every feature using the [BeforeFeature] hook

If i run a feature in isolation, all works
If i run all feature files, i get an I/O error where the config file is being used by another process

I have changed the hook to [BeforeTestRun] and it doesnt run the tests
I have placed all the scenarios in one feature file and they seem to get in each others way

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There's [a constructor for XPathDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te0h7f95(v=vs.100).aspx) that just takes the file name to load, which might behave better.

Comment: Doesn't it run the features, at least their *BeforeFeature* hooks, in parallel?

Comment: What exactly is the IO Error type ? For instance FileNotFoundException or UnauthorizedAccessException etc. Theres probably a clue there.

Comment: OK now its complaining about not accessing the log file:  Sustem.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file xxxxx because ir is being used by another process

Comment: OK so i have an xml file in an external dir that houses the URL and browser type for my test run, it is accessed by the code posted above and that is housed in a method called InitializeSettings

Comment: i have a class called HookInitialize which tells the framework before every feature to initialize the settings    
    {
        [BeforeFeature]
        public static void TestStart()
        {
            InitializeSettings();
            DriverContext.Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        }